# Docker for react native 0.60.5

Tags: android, ios, docker, react-native, teamcity

I'm new with Docker and I would like to use Docker for my react native app...

Does someone has experience with the Docker and has any guide or docker file which can help?

I'm using react native `0.60.5` and as everyone know there's a lot of issues with this version because the `androidX` and the `Hermes` that added to this version.

Another question that I have is about the docker for android and iOS... Are you guys recommend to use Docker only for android or for iOS too?

I have been doing some research and all I could find is docker for android and not for iOS... more than that I couldn't find any "good" tutorial for react native docker, so if someone can share his own docker or any tutorial it could be great

Thank you!

Comment: did you find solution?